# error when renaming files in python

Tags: python, filesystems, rename

I am trying to rename some files, and i think python is well suited...

the files have the pattern
`xxx000xxx000abcde.jpg`   (random numbers and letters followed by a specific letter sequence, say "abcde")

and need to be renamed 
`xxx000xxx000.jpg`   (without the "abcde" at the end)

i tried

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("C:/test/temp/jpg"):   
   os.rename(filename, filename[:len(filename)-10]+".jpg")
```

But i get an error "The system cannot find the file specified"

what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you

stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\rename_jpg\rename_jpg.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, filename[:len(filename)-10]+".jpg")
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: print the whole traceback please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely caused by the Python script not being in C:/test/temp itself.
Python will look for the filenames in the directory it's being run from, meaning it will try to rename files that do no exist.

You'd have to add the destination prefix to the filenames:

```
os.rename("C:/test/temp/" + filename, "C:/test/temp/" + filename[:len(filename)-10]+".jpg")
```

Comment: unfortunately that is not the case... the dir stated only contains the jpgs that need to be renamed, i tried to make it as simple as possible

Comment: Not sure I follow - mind trying to clarify it a little more? I updated my code as it was missing some slashes.